# Create a new data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with only one column. Column contain some names. I need change this data frame.

I created a list with some places:

```
voos_inter <- c("PUJ","SCL","EZE","MVD","ASU","VVI")
```

How can i include on this data frame the number of column according the names of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Is a vector your *one column data frame*? You can convert a `vector` to a `data.frame` and add columns. I use to add columns with `NA` and add values later. Check this example:

```
vtr <-c(1:6)

df <- as.data.frame(vtr)

voos_inter <- c("PUJ","SCL","EZE","MVD","ASU","VVI")

df[,2:(length(voos_inter)+1)] <- NA

names(df)[2:(length(voos_inter)+1)] <- voos_inter

df

  vtr PUJ SCL EZE MVD ASU VVI
1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5   5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
6   6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```